# Regarding the updating of CGridViews in TbRelationalColumn view

Tags: php, yii

In my TbRelationalColumn view page, I have the javascript which refreshes the sub-grid in the view on click of the action button. But if the user opens multiple sub-grids, the grid update will work for only the first opened sub-grid.

I think this is because the grid id is not unique for the subgrids. Can anyone please help?

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array
(
'id'=>'main-grid',
     ...
'columns'=>array
(
    array('header'=>'Sl No','value'=>'$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage * $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + ($row+1)', 'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style' =>'text-align: center;'), 'htmlOptions'=> array('style'=>'text-align: center;')),
    array
    (
            'name'=>'indent_no', 'header'=>'Indent No',
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbRelationalColumn',
            'url' => $this->createUrl('indent/view'),
            'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'js:function(tr,rowid,data){}'
    ),
```

indent/view Contents:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array
(
    'id'=>'sub-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>Indent::model()->searchIndentedItems($id),
    "ajaxUpdate"=>true,
    'template'=>"{items}",
    'filter'=>null,
    'columns'=>array
    (
        array
        (
            'header' => 'Actions',
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{block} ',
            'buttons' => array
            (
                'block'=>array
                (
                        'url' =>'Yii::app()->createUrl("indent/block", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                        'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/block.jpg',
                        'options'=>array(''),
                        'click'=>"function(){ 
                                      $.ajax({'type':'post', 'url':$(this).attr('href'),
                                      'success':function(data){ if ( data.substring(1,8) != 'success') { alert(data); } else { $.fn.yiiGridView.update('sub-grid'); } exit; },
                                      'error':function(xhr, status, error){ alert(xhr.responseText);exit; }}); return false;}",
                        'visible'=>  '($data->indented_item_status == "Active")  && User::model()->checkAccess("Block Indented Item")?"1":"0";',
                ),
            ),
        )   
    )
)
); ?>
```

Comment: `TbRelationalColumn` is not official class, second you are right about id conflicts, generate with random number attatched to id

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick reply. But how to attach random number in $.fn.yiiGridView.update('sub-grid')? Could you please help?

Comment: If I set the id of the sub-grid as 'id'=>rand(0, 99999), then how will I refer to it in $.fn.yiiGridView.update(???)

Comment: put it in a variable before initializing the grid, then wherever you need to refer to it, use that variable

Comment: I tried $gridId = rand(0, 99999);
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array
('id'=> $gridId, ... and $.fn.yiiGridView.update($gridId). But now the whole subgrid disappears when refreshed.

Comment: check the generated html to see exactly what is the output, I think you are missing quotes: `$.fn.yiiGridView.update('$gridId') `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59488/discussion-between-ammamon-and-tinybyte).